# Dataadapter for each datagridview wont work

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, dataadapter

I have 3 datagridviews

> datagridview1, datagridview2, datagridview3

each datagridview is being bind using different data adapters and different bindings

> datapter1, dataadapter2, dataadapter3, binding1 binding2 and binding3

```
'binding dgv1 
datapter1.SelectCommand = mycmd
datapter1.Fill(Dset, "something")
binding1.DataSource = Dset.Tables("something1")
datagridview1.DataSource = binding1

'binding dgv2 
datapter2.SelectCommand = mycmd
datapter2.Fill(Dset, "something")
binding2.DataSource = Dset.Tables("something2")
datagridview2.DataSource = binding2

'binding dgv3 
datapter3.SelectCommand = mycmd
datapter3.Fill(Dset, "something")
binding3.DataSource = Dset.Tables("something3")
datagridview3.DataSource = binding3
```

When the time I wanted to update my datagridview1

```
Dim firstbuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder(Me.dataadapter1)
Me.dataadapter1.Update(Me.binding1.DataSource)
Me.binding1.ResetBindings(False)
```

it prompts me with an error that

> Missing the DataColumn 'located in datagridview3' in the DataTable 'of datagridview3' for the source column 'located in datagridview3'

I don't see why I have this error since I used different bindings and different dataadapters for each datagridview.
Need some help to fix the issue...

Comment: Are using the same `DataSet` instance and table name with each of the `Fill` calls, or is that just because you modified it for the sample code?

Comment: I am using the same dataset... is that something I should not do?

Comment: and yes this is a modified source code just for showcase

Comment: I believe you will need either separate `DataSet`s for each, or at least use different `DataTable` names in a single `DataSet` - otherwise the only data you have left is the last one loaded.

Comment: I edited the question. I'm using different tables in each Dset.

Comment: ive tried using Dset1,Dset2,Dset3 for each dgv but its still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have struggled with the same issue for days some years ago... I created a custom Class in the end. Basically I created separate DataAdapters and -Commandbuillder for each DataTable. Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it works:

```
'1 Dataset for the full DB
Public dbDataSet As New DataSet With {.CaseSensitive = False}

'1 Datatable, Dataadapter en Commandbuilder per TABLE
Private Listof_Datatables As New List(Of DataTable)
Private Listof_Dataadapters As New List(Of OleDbDataAdapter)
Private Listof_Command As New List(Of OleDbCommand)
Private Listof_Commandbuilder As New List(Of OleDbCommandBuilder)

Public Sub Load_Table(tablename As String)
    'Load the AccessTable to the DataSet
    Dim SQLstring As String = "SELECT * FROM " & tablename.ToUpper
    Dim dbCon As New OleDbConnection(_DBconnString_full)
    dbCon.Open()
    Listof_Dataadapters.Add(New OleDbDataAdapter)
    Listof_Command.Add(New OleDbCommand(SQLstring, dbCon))
    Listof_Dataadapters(Listof_Dataadapters.Count - 1).SelectCommand = Listof_Command(Listof_Command.Count - 1)
    Listof_Commandbuilder.Add(New OleDbCommandBuilder(Listof_Dataadapters(Listof_Dataadapters.Count - 1)))
    Listof_Commandbuilder(Listof_Commandbuilder.Count - 1).QuotePrefix = "["
    Listof_Commandbuilder(Listof_Commandbuilder.Count - 1).QuoteSuffix = "]"
    Listof_Dataadapters(Listof_Dataadapters.Count - 1).Fill(dbDataSet, tablename)
    Listof_Datatables.Add(dbDataSet.Tables(tablename))

    'Get primary keys
    Dim UCollist As New List(Of String)
    Dim mySchema As DataTable = CType(dbCon, OleDbConnection).GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, tablename})
    Dim columnOrdinalForName As Integer = mySchema.Columns("COLUMN_NAME").Ordinal
    For Each r As DataRow In mySchema.Rows
        UCollist.Add(r.ItemArray(columnOrdinalForName).ToString)
    Next

    'Set primary keys
    Dim keycolumn(UCollist.Count) As DataColumn
    For index = 0 To UCollist.Count - 1
        keycolumn(index) = dbDataSet.Tables(tablename).Columns(UCollist(index))
    Next
    dbDataSet.Tables(tablename).PrimaryKey = keycolumn

    dbCon.Close()
End Sub
Public Sub Update_Tables()
    Dim NrAdap As Integer = Listof_Dataadapters.Count
    For Adapterindex = 0 To NrAdap - 1
        Listof_Dataadapters(Adapterindex).Update(dbDataSet.Tables(Adapterindex))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: at first your answer is tricky. but to read the code top to bottom its very understandable. thank you for this one!